# How to stop a job when 'WithRepeatCount' done in C#

Tags: c#, quartz.net

How can i stop my job in quartz.net 2.6.1. When `WithRepeatCount` is done it's still running background even I close the application. I mean i want to run `scheduler.Shutdown()`  when count complete.

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
    trigger.StartTrigger();
}

private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
    trigger.StopTrigger();
}

[DisallowConcurrentExecution]/**/
class Job : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        IsConnected.CheckConnection();
    }
}
class Trigger
{
    private IScheduler Start()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();
        return sched;

    }
    private IScheduler Stop()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Shutdown();
        return sched;
    }

    public void StartTrigger()
    {
        IScheduler sched = Start();
        IJobDetail Job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().WithIdentity("Job", null).Build();
            ISimpleTrigger TriggerJob =
            (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder
            .Create()
            .WithIdentity("Job")
            .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
            .WithRepeatCount(4)
            )
            .Build();
            sched.ScheduleJob(Job, TriggerJob);
            sched.Start();
    }
    public void StopTrigger()
    {
            IScheduler sched = Stop();
            sched.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by its running in the back ground? Are you taking a thread dump and seeing quartz thread pool still being available?

Comment: I mean when the method running the thread never ending and if i close the application(btw wpf) it's still running only i can kill it in task manager.

Comment: It is not really clear what do you want to achieve. If you want only to call a method 4 times, why do you don't use just a simple loop? Calling a job a couple of times immediately after its run and then stopping the scheduler, make no sense in my opinion. Btw. you call `sched.Start();` 2 times in your code. Please clarify what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to take a look in quartz [listeners](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html) and figure it out how to get the count:

```
IScheduler sched = Start();
IJobDetail jobDetail = GetJobDetail();
var listener = new CountJobListener();
sched.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(listener, KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(jobDetail.Key));
sched.Start();
```

Implement your own listener:

```
internal class CountJobListener : IJobListener
{
    public void JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
    }

    public void JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
    }

    public void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
    {
        if (GetCount() >= 4)
        {
            context.Scheduler.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    private int GetCount()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Name { get { return "CountJobListener"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If **.WithIntervalInSeconds(1) .WithRepeatCount(4)** means it will run for 5 second then it will still run untill forever on background. So if i add **Thread.Sleep(4000); and sched.Shutdown();** **after sched.Start();** it will run 5 sec then it will be closed.The code should be like this ;

```
  public void StartTrigger()
        {
            try
            {
                IScheduler sched = Start();
                IJobDetail Job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().WithIdentity("Job", null).Build();
                ISimpleTrigger TriggerJob =
                                   (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder
                                   .Create()
                                   .WithIdentity("Job")
                                   .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
                                   .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                                   .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
                                   .RepeatForever()
                                   //.WithRepeatCount(4)
                                   .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithExistingCount())
                                   .Build();
                sched.ScheduleJob(Job, TriggerJob);
                sched.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(4T000);
                sched.Shutdown();
            }
```